# Calculate Angle from direction vector

Tags: vector, geometry, direction

I have direction vector (0.000000, 0.707107, 0.707107) like this, i want to convert this vector to an angle between X, Y and Z direction planes and Direction vectors (0,45 deg,45 deg). Please provide the mathematical equations or VBA functions to get an angle.

[image: check this Image for Angle Measurement]

Comment: `Please provide the mathematical equations or VBA functions to get an angle.` - SO is not a research service. Learn some basic vector math / linear algebra, and attempt to write the code yourself, before asking here.

Comment: thanks @meowgoesthedog. it is very simple.    Cos(theta) = (U.V)/(|U||V|)

Comment: It is indeed very simple - in-fact, simple enough to be easily Googled.

Answer (score -1):

To get angle between vector `D = (dx, dy, dz)` and coordinate planes, you can use scalar product of vector and its projection onto corresponding plane.

For example, to get projection on OYZ plane, you can just make x-component zero.

```
P(0yz) = (0, dy, dz)
S = D.dot.P = 0 + dy * dy + dz * dz
Fi(D, 0yz) = ArcCosine(S / (length(P) * length(D))  = 
   ArcCosine((dy*dy + dz*dz) / Sqrt((dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz)*(dy*dy + dz*dz)))= 
   ArcCosine(Sqrt((dy*dy + dz*dz) /(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz))))= 
   ArcCosine(length(P) / length(D))
```

You can build similar formulas for OXY and OXZ planes